# Prevent SQL Injection in SELECT statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, sql-injection

I am using VS2005 C# ASP.NET and SQL Server 2005.

I have a *search* function on my asp page and I feel that my *SELECT* query is vulnerable to SQL injection.

This is my current *SELECT* statement:

```
string LoggedInUser = (User.Identity.Name);

SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [TABLE1] where [" + DropDownList1.Text + "] like '%" + searchTB.Text + "%' AND [empUser] LIKE '%"+LoggedInUser+"%'";
SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
```

*where `searchTB` is my search text box; `DropDownList1` is my search category; and `LoggedInUser` is the username of the logged in user.

---

I have implemented parameter instead of concatenation in one of my *INSERT* statement:

```
string sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO [TABLE2] (Username) VALUES (@Username)");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", usernameTB.Text);
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

---

I would like to change my *SELECT* statement like my *INSERT* statement, using parameter instead. May I know how should I change it?

Thank you

Comment: Any problems with my answer ? Do you need more help ?

Answer (score 4):

You can add parameters to your selectcommand using

```
SqlDataSource s = new SqlDataSource();
s.SelectParameters.Add("paramName", "paramValue");
```

There are other parameter collections for delete, update and insert too.

```
s.DeleteParameters
s.UpdateParameters
s.InsertParameters
```

More Information:

[MSDN: SqlDataSource.SelectParameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectparameters.aspx)

[Programmatically Using SqlDataSource](http://surinder.computing-studio.com/post/2008/02/17/Programmatically-Using-SqlDataSource.aspx)

**hope this helps**

Answer (score 2):

Write a method that gets the data sourse and use sql parameters for the query. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) is a good example how to add parameters in a command object

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;
```

I would use a method for the query so that I separate the Database Access from the UI functionality. Also, this allows to reuse the query.

Answer (score 2):

See [Using Parameters with the SqlDataSource Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad.aspx)

And [SqlDataSource.SelectParameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectparameters.aspx)

You can specify `SelectParameters` Property for SqlDataSource to use parameterized SQL query

Answer (score 1):

It's not a straightforward task to dynamically specify a fieldname in query, so I'd suggest just doing switch/case validation for field name, like this:

```
switch (DropDownList1.Text)
{
    case "ValidField1":
    case "ValidField2":
    ...
        break;
    default: 
        throw new ArgumentException(...); // or prevent query execution with some other statement
}

SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [TABLE1] where [" + DropDownList1.Text + "] like @value AND [empUser] LIKE @user";
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("value", "%" + searchTB.Text + "%");
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("user", "%"+LoggedInUser+"%");
SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
```

Comment: what do I put in my `case "ValidFied1". Can give me an example? Thks

Comment: @RUiHAO: All values from DropDownList1 or (this should be the same) all field names from TABLE1 which user is allowed to perform search on. This is necessary to prevent sending arbitrary content (SQL Injection) in `DropDownList1.Text` field.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can simply use a filter expression for the SQL datasource [SQL Datasource filter expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59bfya48.aspx)
2. You can write your own select function method with object datasource/datatable